# How can I get that two similarly typed words mean the same thing using Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Say, for example, that I have three words "New York", "new york" and "new-york". Could I get that these three words are referring to the same thing, using machine learning or any other string manipulation algorithm?

I guess that this question must have been answered somewhere, but I really don't know how to look for it. So, I'm sorry if I'm spamming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Normalize the strings, lower case, remove the special characters, get a signature string.
   e.g.

   New york --> newyork
   new-york --> newyork
   NewYork  --> newyork
2. First compare the signatures for exact match.
3. Then compare the signatures using a fuzzy matching algorithm like levenstein, or jaro wrinkler.

   newyork <--> newyerk  --> 90% match
4. Most programming languages have modules available for 3, examples being difflib in python.

You can use python utility method given [here](https://github.com/dhruvpathak/misc-python-utils/blob/master/helpers.py#L115)

```
>>> from helpers import find_string_similarity
>>> find_string_similarity('new york','New-York',normalized=True)
1.0
>>> find_string_similarity('new yArk','New-York',normalized=True)
0.8999999999999999
```

You can plainly use `difflib` too.

Answer (score 1):

I think word2vec is the closest machine-learning-based method to what you want. it will create similar vectors for these sequences, but the results won't be amazing.
I would either use a paraphrase database:
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~ccb/ppdb/
or just a parser like spacy that can normalize text.